# How to synchronize a vector and its subset

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, graph

I have a graph implementation that uses vectors to store its nodes and edges (objects).

```
class Node
{
    int index;
    std::vector<Edge*> from;
    std::vector<Edge*> to;
};

class Edge
{
    int index;
    Node *from;
    int indexFrom;
    Node *to;
    int indexTo;
};

class Graph
{
    std::vector<Node*> nodes;
    std::vector<Edge*> edges;
};
```

The indexes are updated whenever the graph structure changes via a swap-with-last trick. Basically on removal I swap the element-to-be-removed with the last one (including the indexes). This graph structure gives me O(1) on all operations at the cost of inconsistent order of elements in the vectors (but consistent indexes on the elements).

Now I struggle implementing decently efficient **subgraph**. The first instinct is to use vectors like in the main graph to store only the relevant elements.

```
class Subgraph
{
    std::vector<Node*> nodes; //subset of Graph::nodes
    std::vector<Edge*> edges; //subset of Graph::edges
};
```

However suddenly such a sub-graph performs in linear time or worse because when traversing I need to check every edge for presence in the sub-graph, when removing I need to look it up first in the sub-vector.

Now I am trying to figure out how to do this and get at least O(1) for traversal (or rather, checking the presence of an element in the subgraph) and at worst O(log n) for the rest (removals, insertions).

So far I figured vector of bools shadowing the original vectors could do the trick. But maybe there is a better way?

Comment: I don't see how edge removal is O(1). You have to search the from node's and the to node's vector, to find the edge you're removing. That's going to be O(n). The best complexity I think you can get, here, is logarithmic complexity, using node and edge identifiers, and std::set-s, instead of vectors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah silly me. I forgot to include the node vectors indexes in the edges (edited them in). But yeah, I am also afraid I can't do better than log complexity in the sub-graphs...